# Mapping GPS points on processing layer

Tags: java, gps, processing, visualization

I am new to processing tool and using Java to implement my algorithms. I want to visualize GPS points of a trajectory on a map (both of them should be in the same coordinate- I want it to be a projected coordinate in order to perform various spatial analysis). I searched a lot on processing home page and some tutorials. But I didn't get any clue how to map GPS points on a map in processing canvas? Any suggestions or good tutorial for this?

Comment: There are several libraries for rendering geospatial data available on the Processing library page: https://processing.org/reference/libraries/

Comment: Break your problem into steps you can complete or ask more specific questions about. Asking for such a massive answer is unlikely to get much help. However, I've posted a start for you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is convert coordinates from latitude/longitude to the screen. For that, you'll want to use `map()`, which scales values from one range to another.

For example, latitude goes from +90º at the north pole, 0º at the equator, and -90º at the south pole. If your sketch is 600 pixels high, you would use:

```
float y = map(latitude, 90,-90, 0,height);
```

Of course, different [map projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) will make this much more difficult. The ["equirectangular"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) projection is made up of equally-sized squares. It distorts the landforms, but makes writing code very easy.

I have some [mapping demos for Processing](https://github.com/jeffThompson/ProcessingTeachingSketches/tree/master/Mapping) – I think [this one](https://github.com/jeffThompson/ProcessingTeachingSketches/blob/master/Mapping/MapGPSCoordsToScreen/MapGPSCoordsToScreen.pde) will be most helpful.